# DataFormatString from a dataset, by code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I have selected a bunch of data from my access database which one of the fields is a DateTime field.

I'm trying to show it formated in a GridView but when I try:

```
dtlJob.DataSource = genericDataSet
dtlJob.Fields(2).DataFormatString = "{0:d}"
dtlJob.DataBind()
```

I get this error on line 2

```
Error   2   'DataFormatString' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'.
```

How do I format my data?

### EDIT

This is my DetailsGridView I'm trying t o show off

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dtlJob" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px">

</asp:DetailsView>
```

it has nothing but its tags for I'm fetching every data by code from a database. But I want to format the `Data` Date Field which is appearing like this no more which data it has
[image]

Comment: Can you please post your GridView definition from ASPX file?

Comment: Sure.. it has nothing but its tags for I'm fetching every data by code from a database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a BoundField like the code below.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="false" Height="50px" Width="125px">
<Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Age"  HeaderText="Age" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Birth"  HeaderText="Birth" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
 </Fields>
 </asp:DetailsView>
```

I hope that helped.

Vicente

Comment: I did it but the field duplicates

Comment: Should it format whenever the Datafield Value match with the Field Name in the Dataset?

Answer (score 1):

The fields property is readonly, so you can't modify it except in constructor. 
Please notice that I have not tested this solution, bt this is what I think you have to do.

So you have to create a new class that inherits from details view and shadows the Fields property, using its own private _fields field:

```
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Public Class CustomDetailsView
    Inherits DetailsView

    Private _fields As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection
    Public Shadows Property Fields As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection
        Get
            Return _fields
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection)
            _fields = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then you have the following code, creating a CustomDetailsView object, telling it that its datasource is the dataset, formatting the second column field, and giving all hese information to your detaisview on the web form, before binding the data.

```
    Dim myDetailsView = New CustomDetailsView
    myDetailsView.DataSource = genericDataSet
    CType(myDetailsView.Fields(1), BoundField).DataFormatString = "{0:d}"
    dtlJob = myDetailsView
    dtlJob.DataBind()
```

BoundField's base type is DataControlField, so you can write the CType line.
I can't test this right now, please do it and post feedback. If it doesn't work, it could be a beginning of answer.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another solution (still not tested). Here you still make a new class inheriting DetailsView, and you access the fields variable in the constructor:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class _CustomDetailsView
    Inherits DetailsView
    Public Sub New(ByVal Columns As List(Of String))

        For Each item As String In Columns
            Dim bfield As New BoundField
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item) Then
                bfield.DataFormatString = item
            Else
                bfield.DataFormatString = ""
            End If
            Me.Fields.Add(bfield)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, you create a list of string containing the wanted formatting for each column. Then you create your _CustomDetailsView by passing this list of string in the constructor.
Next you assign your DtlJob the _CustomDetailsView object, and finally you provide the datasource and proceed the databinding:

```
    Dim DataFieldStyles = New List(Of String)
    ' First column: Default style
    ' Second column: Date format
    ' Third : Currency Format
    ' Fourth : Default style
    DataFieldStyles.AddRange(New String() {"", "{0:d}", "{0:c}", ""})

    Dim My_DetailsView As _CustomDetailsView = New _CustomDetailsView(DataFieldStyles)
    dtlJob = My_DetailsView
    dtlJob.DataSource = genericDataSet
    dtlJob.DataBind()
```

Same remark as for my other answer, I can't test this, so try it and please give feedback.

Greetings